# Onload event working on one page but not another

Tags: javascript, asp.net, alert, onload

I have a website I am building and I wanted to create an onload event.

I have created a function called first_load() which I want to run as the onload event.  I have this in an external file called NewsScroller.js in the JavaScript directory.

```
function first_load() {
    alert("hello");
}
```

I have the following in my master asp.net page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>MIS portal</title>
    <link href="Styles.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/NewsScroller.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="first_load()">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div id="topbanner">
            <Homemade:WarningBar runat="server" ID="WarningLine" />
        </div>
        <div id="secondbanner">
            <asp:contentplaceholder id="CPH1" runat="server">
            </asp:contentplaceholder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the default.aspx into the contentplaceholder, the alert pops up.  When I click a link in the default.aspx file which takes me to my contact.aspx page, the alert fails to popup and I get an "Object Expected" Error message in IE9.

Can anyone tell me why its working in one page and not the other?

Comment: please post more code.

Comment: Are you loading your external file in your contact.aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With near 100% certainty I can say that your contact.aspx page is not referencing the javascript file that the `first_load()` method is located in.

Things to check:

1. Are you actually referencing it?
2. If you *think* so, is the path correct?

If you are referencing it out of a master page AND the contact.aspx page is not in the same directory as the master page AND you are using a relative path from the master, then it's likely you aren't doing it right and need to switch to root relative paths.

Comment: Thanks, I think your onto something.  My Default.aspx isn't at the same level as the contact.aspx in the folder heirarchy.  When I changed the <script src="" > to ../ it worked in most of the other pages except for default.aspx.  I looked to do src="~/..." but it doesn't seem to work for either now :s any suggestions for a relative path?

Comment: I've had to reference the javascript file as its absolute path, "https://etc/etc/etc/JavaScript/NewsScroller.js to get it to work on both pages

Comment: @chris31389: the `~/` only works when asp.net is processing the "control".  You could try changing your script tag to be `<script runat="server" src="~/whatever" />` but I'm not certain that would work.